# Create Spatial Index in PostGIS on an entire Schema

Tags: postgis, spatial-index

I have loaded a number of shapefiles using SPIT (QGIS plugin) to my PostGIS database.  These layers did not have a Spatial Index created upon loading.  I am wondering if there is a way to create a Spatial Index for each layer in the schema without writing a query for each layer.  I am not a good PostGIS script writer, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to batch create indexes on geometry columns, you could try this plpgsql function I've just knocked up:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION BatchIndex(sn text, tn text, cn text) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE i_exists integer;
DECLARE idxname text;
BEGIN
  idxname := 'idx_' || tn || '_' || cn;
  select into i_exists count(*) from pg_class where relname = idxname;

  IF i_exists = 0 THEN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX ' ||idxname || ' ON '
      || sn || '.' || tn
      || ' USING GIST(' || cn || ')';
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I've not tried it in anger on my database, but it seems to do the job.

To use it, just run a `SELECT` statement like this:

```sql
select BatchIndex('public', f_table_name, f_geometry_column) from geometry_columns where f_table_schema = 'public';
```

To create indexes on all geometry columns, you can use it like this:

```sql
select BatchIndex(f_table_schema, f_table_name, f_geometry_column) from geometry_columns;
```

Afterwards, run a `VACUUM ANALYZE` to tidy everything up.

Comment: Thank you so much, this looks great.  I have run this, but there seems to be an issue, mind you, this could be from my lack of scripting ability.  But when I run the SELECT statements I get the following error:

ERROR:  function batchindex(unknown, character varying, character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: select BatchIndex('public', f_table_name, f_geometry_column)...

I am not sure if I am to add anything to get the batch, or if this is just a place holder for something different.  The CREATE query ran through without an issue, but no indexes were generated.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure what's happening there then. The fact that it thinks the first parameter you're passing is of type `unknown` rather than `character varying` is setting off alarm bells, but I can't see where it has a problem. I'll give it some thought, meanwhile any PostgreSQL gurus out there fancy giving it a go? :)

Answer (score 2):

say your table is 'building', you can index using GIST

```
CREATE INDEX building_gindx ON building USING GIST (geom);
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks Naresh, no I am looking for a way to create indexes for all tables in a schema, in a batch system.

Answer (score 2):

The top answer won't work if you have views with geometry. Changing the 'IF' statement to check that you're not trying to build a index on a view solves that issue. If you do wish to use views with geometry,
replace this line:

```
IF i_exists = 0
```

with this:

```
IF i_exists = 0 AND tn IN (SELECT table_name, table_type FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```